# iOS: Customize assistive touch menu and add my application launcher in top level menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, customization, assistive

I wish to add the application to the assistive menu of iOS. The core idea is to access a certain functionality of the application instantaneously, (think of it like if the kid is taking first step and parents cant wait to go through the iPhone to open camera, instead they open it from assistive touch and instantaneously take picture, but in my case, its not a base app from iOS, rather a custom app created by myself)

(PS: Must be in swift)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of iOS 10, Apple provides no API to support augmenting the functionality/behavior of Assistive Touch.